# Google Maps não funciona no Celular

Tags: javascript, html, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Eu tenho este código HTML abaixo e costumava funcionar, de repente o mapa não carrega mais e eu não consigo resolver o problema. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Eu testo no Firefox e no Google Chrome do Android.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> 
<title>Tz0 Mobile Maps</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
 html { height: 100% } 
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 } 
#map_canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% } 
 .inputx{font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 11px; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;} 
</style>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var map = null;

   function initializeMap() {
       var start = new google.maps.LatLng(-29.693142,-51.460755); 
       var myOptions = { zoom : 5, center : start, mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP } 
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 
   }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initializeMap()" scroll="no">
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Funciona normalmente quando eu rodo no desktop.

Comment: Há algum erro no console?

Comment: nenhum, o mapa simplesmente não carrega, a página fica em branco.